# Flutter set container colors depends on state

Tags: flutter

i have a problem in my flutter project.

i have a task list screen and i want to change widget colors when task is completed, like disabled buttons(pale colors) but it can be tapped

this is my screen:

[image]

codes: [image]

**this is my widget**

```
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 7, bottom: 7),
    height: GeneralConstants.instance.popupBoxHeight,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
        color: ColorConstants.instance.mainColor),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print("${baslik} Clicked");
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: AutoSizeText(
              baslik,
              style: GoogleFonts.oswald(
                  color: ColorConstants.instance.headerColor, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: true,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  AutoSizeText(
                    govde,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        color: ColorConstants.instance.bodyColor, fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions to solve it:

1. You can send the row color from outside and if the task is done send a pale color. For more information please read [this article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).
2. If you return `null` on InkWell onTap it becomes disabled and shows a pale color. But I'm sure `InkWell` shows a shadow when you click it, I suggest you use [GestureDetector widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) for a clickable widget.

Comment: thank you for your response. i thought to same way like you but i think maybe there is a easy way to do.